# Spring Transaction Management and Oracle Stored procedures

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, transactions

I am currently integrating transaction management into my code.

I am trying to set it up against stored procedures that already exist.

The stored procedures have a commit at the end of them.

In my eclipse console, I can see the transaction management code being invoked

```
datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager Initiating transaction rollback
datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@1544055]
datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@1544055] after transaction
```

But I can still see remains of the record that should have been rolled back in my database tables.

If we use spring transaction management, should we remove all commits from our stored procedures?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: *if we use spring transaction management, should we remove all commits from our stored procedures* yes :-)

Comment: @Damien Were you able to find out the solution for this issue?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I have the same case, is there any thing we can do with Spring itself instead of changing the procedure code.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal you can manage your transactions on any layer (service, repository, db), and there are valid arguments for each. Personally, I lean toward managing transactions on the service level, i.e. in Spring. But however you do it, you should do it on one layer only (either use explicit transactions in your procedures or declarative Transactions in Spring, but not both)

Comment: That said, you can fine-tune your Spring transaction support through `@Transactional`'s `propagation` attribute, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html). Perhaps something like [`Propagation.REQUIRED`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) works for you.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks you so much for your prompt response. It helped us.